# {Magento} Product page and Add To Cart

Tags: magento

I am building a static page that contains several products. I took the static HTML that was generated by one of my product pages and added all the other products to this page. Each product has a radio button and the customer can only select one of them. The qty will always be 1.

How do I submit the product_addtocart_form?

I modified the form submit function like this:

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm("product_addtocart_form");
productAddToCartForm.submit = function(){
  if(this.validator.validate()) {
    var product_id = jQuery("input[name='product']:checked").val();
    this.form.action = "/store/checkout/cart/add/product/"+product_id+"/qty/1";
    this.form.submit();
  }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

But it doesn't always work. If I modify the action to this, which is the same as my product page but changing the product_id:

```
this.form.action = "/store/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcuY2ljLnNjaWMuY29tL3N0b3JlL3B1YmxpY2F0aW9ucy8yNS1tb3N0LWlubm92YXRpdmUtYWdlbnRzLWluLWFtZXJpY2EuaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/"+product_id+"/qty/1";
```

It also works inconsistenty.

How do I do this??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just post the form as an `action="get"` to `/checkout/cart/add`

Name your radio field `product` and another hidden field named `qty`.  Pass the Magento product ID to `product` and the quantity to `qty`

Comment: Already tried that with no success. How I remedied it is I got rid of the form altogether and then just redrected in the .click to  /store/checkout/cart/add/product/"+product_id+"/qty/1